# Wpf ListBox binding is not registering any content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a Wpf ListBox and it wont recognise my binding to an observable collection.

my wpf code is

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="267" Margin="0,0,0,-12">
     <ListBox x:Name="quote_list" DisplayMemberPath="Body" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=QuotesList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="289" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
     <TextBlock x:Name="count_label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="16" Width="52">
        <Run Text="Count("></Run>
        <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=quote_list, Path=Items.Count, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
        <Run Text=")"></Run>
     </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

so the listbox should be bound to a variable named `QuotesList`

On my C# side i have the following

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Quote> QuotesList;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            QuotesList = new ObservableCollection<Quote>();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

        }
```

later in my code i have an add method which looks like

```
Quote quote = new Quote();
quote_identifier.Text = quote.Identifier.ToString();
quote.Author = quote_author.Text;
quote.Body = quote_body.Text;
quote.Title = quote_title.Text;
quote.Source = quote_source.Text;

QuotesList.Add(quote);
```

but when that is added to the list,(i debugged to make sure) it does not show up in the ListBox. Am i missing some step?

Comment: You cannot bind to a field. Convert it into property `public ObservableCollection<Quote> QuotesList {get; set;}`

Comment: well then.... adding that {get;set;} solved the issue.... do you want to write this as an answer so i can give you the correct mark?

Answer (score 2):

As I've mentioned in the comment you cannot bind to a field so you'll need to convert it into property

```
public ObservableCollection<Quote> QuotesList {get; set;}
```

As described in the [Binding Sources Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object.** The binding engine uses CLR reflection to get the values of the properties. Alternatively, objects that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or have a registered TypeDescriptionProvider also work with the binding engine.

Answer (score 0):

That has happened to me and I have solved creating the NotifyPropertyChanged

Then use it like this:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(()=>QuotesList);
```